# How To Change Django Folder Directory

Tags: django

How to change the default static file directory in django. currentyly i'm using this directory:-

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'static').replace('\\','/')
```

I want to change it in my directory in my server for example :-

```
/var/www/html/uploaded/
```

Comment: Good advice from Hedde because your alternative to change it on your server is to just type it in.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your real question is how to use different settings in different environments (e.g. a [DTAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development,_testing,_acceptance_and_production) architecture). There's an ongoing discussion within the django mailing list about settings if you're interested.

You could use a different python file in deployment, e.g.

```
settings.py
settings_deployment.py
```

Example of the latter's content

```
from settings import *

DEBUG = False

MEDIA_ROOT = "/var/www/static/"
```

Then be sure to load settings_deployment instead of settings on your server.

Another, more dynamic approach would be to overload settings based on an environment setting, its not very hard to fabricate something like that in plain python.